# Resource not found: domain while inserting a new user with Google API

Tags: json, google-api, http-status-code-404, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to insert a new user under my Google Admin account:

```
def insertNewUser(directory_service):
  params = {
    'name': {
      'familyName': 'Testfamilyname',
      'givenName': 'TestgivenName',
    },
    'password': 'testpassword',
    'primaryEmail': 'testemail@mycompanydomain',
  }
  result = directory_service.users().insert(body=params).execute()
```

After executing this code I get the following error message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json returned "Resource Not Found: domain">
```

I have no idea what can it mean and how to solve the problem? Are there any examples of inserting users using Google Admin API?

I tried adding the domain in the request but it didn't help, e.g.:

```
  params = {
    'name': {
      'familyName': 'Testfamilyname',
      'givenName': 'TestgivenName',
    },
    'password': 'testpassword',
    'primaryEmail': 'testemail@mycompanydomain',
    'organizations': {
      'domain': 'mycompanydomain',
    }
  }
```

or:

```
  params = {
    'name': {
      'familyName': 'Testfamilyname',
      'givenName': 'TestgivenName',
    },
    'password': 'testpassword',
    'primaryEmail': 'testemail@mycompanydomain',
    'domain': 'mycompanydomain',
  }
```

I'm quite sure I'm authenticating correctly, since I'm able to execute get-like requests, like list all current users under my account.

I tried to execute the same query using Google API explorer: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert and it works fine there.

I've also seen the following post:
[404 Resource Not Found: domain with Google Direcotry API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767994/404-resource-not-found-domain-with-google-direcotry-api) and maybe the solution is similar, however I couldn't find how to create a user object with the API in Python. There are no examples available either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake. The domain should of course end with ".com".
The correct request is:

```
def insertNewUser(directory_service):
  params = {
    'name': {
      'familyName': 'Testfamilyname',
      'givenName': 'TestgivenName',
    },
  'password': 'testpassword',
  'primaryEmail': 'testemail@mycompanydomain.com',
}
result = directory_service.users().insert(body=params).execute()
```

Comment: I want to do this with php-api-client but i can't find any example about this. Can you help me please?